# MYSQL query syntax error at SET

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I can run the following query in PHPMyAdmin, but for some reason I get a syntax error when I run it in a mysql method in PHP:

```
INSERT INTO product (model, stock_status_id, image, price, date_available, status, date_added, date_modified) 
VALUES('SP44152', 5, 'data/products/SP44152-1.jpg', '18.04', '2012-06-18', 1, '2012-06-19 00:31:35', '2012-06-19 00:57:01'); 
SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
INSERT INTO product_description (product_id, language_id, name, Description) 
VALUES(@lastid, 1, 'Product item 1', 'Product Description'); 
INSERT INTO product_reward (product_id, customer_group_id, points) 
VALUES(@lastid, 1, 0);  
INSERT INTO product_to_category (product_id, category_id) 
VALUES(@lastid, 67); 
INSERT INTO product_to_store (product_id, store_id) VALUES(@lastid, 0);
```

the error code I am getting:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO product_description (product_i' at line 3
```

I have tried removing the ; from the end of each line and I tried removing the field 'status' as I know that is also something you can use in MYSQL. There doesn't seem to be much on the Internet that can help identify the cause on this one.

Any feedback is very welcome.

Comment: why not use php's function mysql_insert_id()? http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: you have problem in your first query, check fields name propperly,put quotes on `status_id` value and on status `value`

Comment: Thanks Feida, I did use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does not like multiple, semi-colon separated statements:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

Break down your query into multiple queries and execute them one-by-one:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product ...", $conn);
$lastid = mysql_insert_id($conn); // you can use mysql_insert_id() PHP function
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_description ...", $conn);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_reward ...", $conn);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_to_category ...", $conn);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_to_store ...", $conn);
```

PS: I suggest that you look at [alternatives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to `mysql_*` functions.